# Cookie based authentication in C#

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, cookies, restsharp

i have big problem with two wpf applications.

We change the authentication on the server from basic http TO cookie based authentication,token. These two apps use RestSharp to authenticate the user with old basic http auth(everything workED fine):

```
try
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://" + _endpointAddr + "/");
    var request = new RestRequest("auth/", Method.GET);

    request.Credentials = _credential;

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) return false;
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK; // Status Code is 403 NOW
}...
```

After the change to cookie based we get statuscode 403 from server. I already read that the restsharp can use cookies. How to edit the code and authenticate the user with cookie based authentication by token? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it by adding this:

```
client.FollowRedirects = false; // very important in my case
... request.addParameters ...
... client.execute(request) ...

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
      if (response.Cookies.Count == 1)
      {
             msg.Cookie = response.Cookies[0].Value;
             msg.ReturnValue = true;
      }
}
```